# ¿Como crear tablas con EntityFrameworks y que se agreguen al modelo mediante codigo?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Estoy Desarrollando un Sistema de Recursos Humanos, donde he utilizado EntityFrameworks llegue a la parte que necesito Crear Tablas mediante la aplicación y poder utilizarlas posteriormente.
¿Se pueden Crear Tabas Dinamicamente con EF ? 
¿Cual Seria el Código?

Answer (score 1):

- Crea un nuevo proyecto de cualquier tipo, si es una `web application` usa las plantillas de `Web API` y `MVC` si quieres trabajar con `REST`, si solo quieres hacer una web con una plantilla de Bootstrap, selecciona solo `MVC`
- Creas un modelo con la clase a la cual quieres crear la tabla, declaras sus propiedades

Por ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TutorialEntityFramework.Models
{
    public class BlogPost
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Contenido { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        public DateTime Publicacion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- Crea tu clase que heredara del `DbContext`

Ejemplo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TutorialEntityFramework.Models
{
    public class BlogContext: DbContext
    {
        public BlogContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }
        public DbSet BlogPosts { get; set; }

    }
}
```

- Abres Nuget Package Manager y ejecutas el comando `enable-migrations`
- En la carpeta `migrations` creada, abre el archivo `configuration.cs`
- Agrega la linea `` y guarda
- Vuelve a Nuget Package Manager y ejecuta el comando `update-database`
- Ya tienes tu base de datos creada, ahora, puedes usarla

*PD: Se supone que deberias tener configurada tu `connectionString` en tu `web.config` antes de hacer todo eso*

Ejemplo

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=TU_SERVIDOR;initial catalog=NOMBRE_DE_BD;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=TU_NOMBRE_DE_USUARIO;Password=TU_CLAVE_DE_BD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```